# Understanding Bernoulli Sequences.

Tags: probability, statistics

A structure with a design life of 50 yr is planned for a site where high intensity earthquakes may occur with a return period of 100 yr. The structure is designed to have a 0.98 probability of not suffering damage within its design life. Damage effects between earthquakes are statistically independent. If occurrence of high intensity earthquake at the site is modeled by Bernoulli sequence what is the probability of damage to the structure under a single earthquake?

My major confusion is how to interpret this condition "The structure is designed to have a 0.98 probability of not suffering damage within its design life."

Does this mean that $P^{50} = 0.98$?

Comment: What do you mean by P in your equation? Is it the probability of an earthquake happening in a specific year?

Comment: Hi! P means the probability of the structure not suffering the damage.

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion arises from a need to precisely define the notation for various events described in the question.

For $i = 1, 2, \ldots$, let $X_i \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p)$ represent the occurrence of a high-intensity earthquake at the structure's site in year $i$; specifically, $X_i = 1$ if there was such an earthquake in year $i$, and $X_i = 0$ otherwise.  We are told the "return period" is $100$ years, i.e., the expected number of such earthquakes in a $100$ year period is $1$, or mathematically, $$\operatorname{E}[X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_{100}] = 1.$$  By the linearity of expectation and the independent and identically distributed property of the $X_i$, this is just $$100 \operatorname{E}[X_1] = 100 p = 1,$$ so $p = 0.01$.  Note that $X_i$ only models earthquakes, not whether they cause damage.  Also note that this Bernoulli model does not allow for more than one earthquake to occur in a given calendar year.

Now we define a second sequence of random variables $Y_i \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(\pi)$, where $Y_i = 1$ if $X_i = 1$ and the earthquake was damaging to the structure.  Then we are told that $$\Pr[Y_1 + Y_2 + \cdots + Y_{50} = 0] = 0.98,$$ that is to say, the probability there are no damaging earthquake events in $50$ years is $0.98$.  From this, we have $$(1-\pi)^{50} = 0.98,$$ or $$\pi \approx 0.000403973.$$  This makes sense because we must have $0 < \pi < p$.  Then given there was an earthquake in year $i$, the probability it was damaging is $$\Pr[Y_i = 1 \mid X_i = 1] = \frac{\Pr[(Y_i = 1) \cap (X_i = 1)]}{\Pr[X_i = 1]} = \frac{\Pr[Y_i = 1]}{\Pr[X_i = 1]} = \frac{0.000403973}{0.01} = 0.0403973.$$  The first equality is by definition of conditional probability; the second is true because the event $Y_i = 1$ is a subset of the event $X_i = 1$:  if there is a damaging earthquake, there must have been an earthquake, so the joint probability simplifies to just the probability of a damaging earthquake.  The rest is straightforward.

Comment: you are really smart! Thank you so much for the explanation! thank you!

Comment: @Harry If your question was answered, please upvote and/or accept it as an answer.